# Разделить список на списки по 2 элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Код:

```
mertebe_say_result = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    mertebe_say_result.append(r'{"text":' + str(i) + ',"callback_data":' + str(i) + '}')

print(mertebe_say_result)
```

Я получаю данные в список `mertebe_say_result = []`

```
[
    '{"text":1,"callback_data":1}', '{"text":2,"callback_data":2}',
    '{"text":3,"callback_data":3}', '{"text":4,"callback_data":4}'
]
```

Мне нужно разделить элементы списка по 2, чтобы был список внутри списка

```
[
    ['{"text":1,"callback_data":1}', '{"text":2,"callback_data":2}],
    ['{"text":3,"callback_data":3}', '{"text":4,"callback_data":4}]
]
```

Comment: почитайте о срезах

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `zip` и `map`:

```
out = list(map(list, zip(mertebe_say_result[::2], mertebe_say_result[1::2])))
print(out)
```

```
[['{"text":1,"callback_data":1}', '{"text":2,"callback_data":2}'], ['{"text":3,"callback_data":3}', '{"text":4,"callback_data":4}']]
```